# Replace a value in array1 with value in array2, when link is clicked, in a DRY way with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs but writing a memory card game to solidify what i've learned so far from tutorials.

**Game Basics**
Cards flips over when a card's link is clicked by user.

There are 2 arrays in the js file,
one array for true values of the cards,
and a second array with values the user sees (so nothing if the card is face-down).
There is a link in the view for each separate value in second array. When the user click a link, the value in the second array is replaced with the value in the same position of first array.

**Problem**
I'm currently writing a separate function for every single card, and it just feels very not DRY.. especially if i want to use 52 cards in a later version of the program. Current version only has 4.

Would love some advice on how to make this cleaner (or any general criticism) :)

**App.js**

```
angular.module('Board', [
])
.controller('BoardCtrl', function($scope) {
    var cards = shuffleArray(['A','K','Q','J']);
    var table = ['?','?','?','?'];

    $scope.a = table[0];
    $scope.b = table[1];
    $scope.c = table[2];
    $scope.d = table[3];

    /* flip card A */
    function flipCardA() {
        $scope.a = cards[0];
    }
    $scope.flipCardA = flipCardA;

    /* flip card B */
    function flipCardB() {
        $scope.b = cards[1];
    }
    $scope.flipCardB = flipCardB;

    /* flip card C */
    function flipCardC() {
        $scope.c = cards[2];
    }
    $scope.flipCardC = flipCardC;

    /* flip card D */
    function flipCardD() {
        $scope.d = cards[3];
    }
    $scope.flipCardD = flipCardD;

});

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Board">
  <head>
    <title>Chat Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-controller="BoardCtrl">
    <div class="container" style="text-align:center">
      <div>
        <li ng-repeat='category in categories'>
          <a href='#' ng-click='setCurrentCategory(category)'>{{category.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#" ng-click='flipCardA()'>{{a}}</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click='flipCardB()'>{{b}}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#" ng-click='flipCardC()'>{{c}}</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click='flipCardD()'>{{d}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of how to make functions with arguments match with arrays in controller.

Following is by no means a complete or 100% efficient solution but greatly simplifies what you are doing

```
app.controller('BoardCtrl', function($scope) {
  var cards = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J'];
  var table = ['?', '?', '?', '?'];

  // set function references from below on scope
  $scope.flipCard = flipCard;
  $scope.setHands = setHands;

  function flipCard(index) {
    $scope.table[index] = cards[index];
  }    

  function setHands() {
    // shuffle
    cards = shuffleArray(cards);
    // make copy of table array in scope
    $scope.table = [].concat(table)
  }
  // initialize first hands
  setHands();

});
```

HTML Sample

```
<a href="#" ng-click='flipCard(0)'>{{table[0]}}</a>

<button  ng-click="setHands()">Reset</button>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wodRBKOSL89MRHbsq7pu?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store each entry in the array as a variable, use angular's ng-repeat directive:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in table" ng-click='flipCard($index)'>{{item}}</a>
</div>
```

Then in your controller you can do this:

```
var cards = shuffleArray(['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J']);
$scope.table = ['?','?','?','?'];
$scope.flipCard = function(index) {
    $scope.table[index] = cards[index];
}
```

Comment: one potential caviat to this is that `$index` is only the element's position in the `ng-repeat`, and while *most of the time* it matches up to the index of the item in the array being iterated, it is not **guaranteed** to do so, especially if filters are added.

Comment: Are you sure that `$index` is not guaranteed to match up with the given collection without filters? I can't find anything suggesting that in the docs.

Comment: Curious. Assuming no filters applied then should be fine to use -ng-repeat?

Comment: I believe so, despite @Claies comment, I have used this for years without problems.